# Test method in component without Enzyme - React Native

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, enzyme

I'm pretty new to React Native and Javascript, I'm currently trying to test methods inside my components, I've seen this being done with Enzyme like

`const wrapper = shallow(<Component/>);

wrapper.instance().methodIwannaCall();`

Coming from the iOS Dev world, I'm having a hard to understanding why it seems to be so complicated to get an instance of a class and call a method on it.

Unfortunately I'm using React `16.0.0-alpha.12`  which means I can't for now use `Enzyme`, which seems to be the library everyone is using to accomplish what I need.

Also notice I'm not using Redux, I suspect this would be less of a pain if I'd use Redux, since that way all my business logic would be within actions and hence would be easier to test.

Any comments/help are greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure `ReactTestUtils` to get instance of your component, for example using [renderIntoDocument](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#renderintodocument) method:

```
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';

const wrapper = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Component/>);
wrapper.methodIwannaCall();
```

Comment: hey @Amid thanks for your answer, I didn't manage to get that to work, and I just read ReactTestUtils won't work with React-Native. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46381217/1932547

Comment: I am sorry - missed your react-native tag. I’ve only used this approach with ordinary react.