# Cannot find module 'react/lib/React' from 'ReactTestUtils.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to set up unit-tests for a react native projects using ReactTestUtils
However I get this error while running npm test:

```
Cannot find module 'react/lib/React' from 'ReactTestUtils.js'
```

I have the feeling my dependencies are not working correctly but I can't find out why. I have already tried downgrading the react version, but this won't solve my problem and tweaking the react-dom version, but I seem not to be able to find the golden combination.

Anyone knows if this is a known issue? I was not able to find any documentation about this here and neither in the react documentation.

This is my package.json configuration:

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "0.0.40",
    "expo": "18.0.3",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
    "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "jest-expo": "~18.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "__coverage__",
    "testRegex": "./__tests__/[^setup].*.js$",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base|react-navigation|react-native-fabric)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./__tests__/setup.js"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing React (web) and React-Native.

ReactTestUtils was made for React and does not work with React-Native. Therefore you need to look elsewhere for unit testing React-Native.
Also you should remove React as a dependency from your project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is that you are relying on react 16 and 15 at the same time. Internals in react/lib/* have completely changed in react 16 so compat is not possible.
You should use everything to react(-*) 16 or 15 but not a mix of both.

Latest Jest and enzyme (v3) now have full compat for react 16 which just came out!